How to insert data carried over from one page into a SQFLITE database row?
I have a field, "designName," that I carry over from a "project" page to one where I enter tasks, and want to insert in a SQFLITE column. For some reason, it can't get it to insert on the first entry, but only on the "updates."
    Future<void> _addItem(String designName, String taskName, String taskType, String taskActivityArea, String taskFunction, String taskComment) async {
      await SQLHelperTasks.createItem(
          _designNameController.text,
          _taskNameController.text,
          _taskTypeController.text,
          _taskActivityAreaController.text,
          _taskFunctionController.text,
          _taskCommentController.text);
      _refreshTasks();
    }


The corresponding code in the "SQLHelper" file:
  static Future<int> createItem(String designName,
      String taskName,
      String? taskType,
      String? taskActivityArea,
      String? taskFunction,
      String? taskComment) async {
    final db = await SQLHelperTasks.db();

    final data = {'designName': designName,
      'taskName': taskName,
      'taskType': taskType,
      'taskActivityArea': taskActivityArea,
      'taskFunction': taskFunction,
      'taskComment': taskComment};
    final id = await db.insert('items', data,
        conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    return id;
  }

The "updates" are basically identical:
    Future<void> _updateItem(id, String designName, String taskName, String taskType, String taskActivityArea, String taskFunction, String taskComment) async {
      await SQLHelperTasks.updateItem(
          id, _designNameController.text,
          _taskNameController.text,
          _taskTypeController.text,
          _taskActivityAreaController.text,
          _taskFunctionController.text,
          _taskCommentController.text);
      _refreshTasks();
    }

And:
  static Future<int> updateItem(
      int id,
      String designName,
      String taskName,
      String? taskType,
      String? taskActivityArea,
      String? taskFunction,
      String? taskComment) async {
    final db = await SQLHelperTasks.db();

    final data = {
      'designName': designName,
      'taskName': taskName,
      'taskType': taskType,
      'taskActivityArea': taskActivityArea,
      'taskFunction': taskFunction,
      'taskComment': taskComment,
      'createdAt': DateTime.now().toString()
    };

Just having trouble with that one field...
Any suggestions?
I can add more code if necessary.
